# how to read and update the values of 'selectInput'

Tags: r, shiny

I want to upload a dataset with a column name `Time`. Then, the code finds the maximum value of the column `Time` and divide it with 4 in order to finds out how many intervals of size 4 exists and then, print out this sequence in the `selectInput`. Here is my code. It works but there is a minor error in the `max(data()$Time)` that I do not understand why it gives `-inf`. The error says `no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf`

Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  fileInput(inputId = "uploadcsv","", accept = '.csv'),
  selectInput("select", label = h3("Select box"), 
              choices = "", 
              selected = 1)

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data <- reactive({
    infile <- input$uploadedcsv

    if (is.null(infile))
      return(NULL)

    read.csv(infile$datapath, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
  })

  observe({
    if (max(data()$Time) %% 4 == 0){
      numberofinterval <- max(data()$Time) %/% 4
    } else {
      numberofinterval <- (max(data()$Time) %/% 4)+1
    }

    NumPeriod <- seq(0, numberofinterval)

    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "select",
                             choices = NumPeriod,
                             selected = NumPeriod)
  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: you could try formatting your variable as a date `as.Date()`, but unless you share you csv, its more or less random guessing,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In the `data` reactive, you read the input field `uploadedcsv`, but in the ui, it's called `uploadcsv` (Note the missing `ed`). If you make this consistent, the upload should work.

2) The `observe` runs when the app starts; at that point `data()` returns `NULL`, so `max(data()$Time` is `max(NULL)`, which is `-Inf`. You should wait until the data is loaded. One way to do this is to change `observe` to `observeEvent`:

```
observeEvent(data, { # and so on...
```

another option is to keep `observe` and add `req(data)` at the beginning of the observer.